# Data Structure in ruby to only store unique elements?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, set

I want a Data Structure in Ruby which will only store a string only once and reject it the next time I try to put it in(Something like a 'SET').
The implementation needs to be the most efficient(Better than a Linear Search in an array for instance).

Also I tried using Hash for the purpose, but multiple strings with same value(these strings I get from slice operation on some existing strings) get into the Hash, seems like a different hash value for them is being computed.

What could be the best and most efficient way out? I would not like to use a ruby gem. I am working on an puzzle solution from an online judge for which I can only submit my own code.

Here is the code snippet I wrote:

```
for string in @string_store do
  for c in 0...string.length
    index_to_sum=0
    while c+index_to_sum<string.length do
      substring=string[c..(c+index_to_sum)]         
      unless @hash_store[substring]=='X'
        @hash_store[substring]='X'
      end
      index_to_sum+=1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Love the Deathnote pic, btw :)

Comment: Are you sure about _"but multiple strings with same value(these strings I get from slice operation on some existing strings) get into the Hash"_? http://ideone.com/eIsMX

Answer (score 7):

How about a [Ruby Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) :)

```
require 'set'
s1 = Set.new [1, 2]                   # -> #<Set: {1, 2}>
s2 = [1, 2].to_set                    # -> #<Set: {1, 2}>
s1 == s2                              # -> true
s1.add("foo")                         # -> #<Set: {1, 2, "foo"}>
s1.merge([2, 6])                      # -> #<Set: {6, 1, 2, "foo"}>
s1.subset? s2                         # -> false
s2.subset? s1                         # -> true
```

Although it uses a `require`, Ruby Set is part of the Ruby standard library so it should be perfectly acceptable for your code submission

Comment: I am facing the same problem even with a Set DS. :|

Answer (score 0):

Of course macek's solution works, but a Hash should definitely work as well.  Using a Hash to store unique lists is a common idiom in languages which don't have native support for sets.  Can you provide a small code example reproducing the problem with duplicate strings?  I suspect that when you convert to using a set, you might run into the same issue.

Comment: @Myth17 given the code above, if you call `@hash_store.keys` you should get your unique list.  Are you saying you see duplicate keys if you call that?

Comment: Yes, The output is -->
aa
aab
aab
ab
ab
b
b

aac
aac
ac
ac
c
c

Comment: @Myth17 you are sure its not a whitespace issue?  Something like "aab" " aab"?  That is very strange.